# Given 2 numbers N and Q followed by N numbers.Now Q inputs of 2 Numbers U and V are given. U indicates the starting index and V indicates the ending

Tags: javascript

Given `2` numbers `N` and `Q` followed by `N` numbers. Now `Q` inputs of `2` Numbers `U` and `V` are given. `U` indicates the starting index and `V` indicates the ending index. So for each `U,V` find the `minimum` of all values of the array from the index `U` to `V`(1 based indexing) Input Size: `N<=100000`
example

**INPUT**

5 3

1 1 1 1 1

1 3

2 4

3 4

**OUTPUT**

1

1

1

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're going to need to clarify your question and show what you've tried so far. [How much research effort is expected of SO users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: This is not even a question. Did you just copy-paste your homework so that we solve it for you?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
const N = 5;
const Q = 3;
const Numbers = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
const UVInputs = [[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]];
const result = [];
for(let i = 0;i < Q;i++)
   result.push(Math.min(...Numbers.slice(UVInputs[i][0], UVInputs[i][1])));
console.log(result);
```